# Proper pushforward of Chow groups

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand proper pushforwards of Chow groups. Let $f:X \to Y$ be a proper morphism of schemes. Suppose $A$ is a subvariety of $X$. Then the pushforward should be $n \cdot [f(A)]$, where $n=[k(A):k(f(A))]$. This multiplicity is there to ensure the pushforward respects rational equivalence.

Is there a simple example that shows the multiplicity is required? Namely, is there any example of a proper morphism where the naive pushforward without multiplicity fails to respect rational equivalence? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: As you probably know, this definition is meant to count 'extra covering' that comes from things like ramification. This tells us that perhaps we best look at the cone $C=V(x^2+y^2-z^2)\subseteq\mathbb{A}^3$. This has class group $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. What if you think about its normalization and a divisor mapping to non-principal divisor?

Comment: Don't we get a simpler example by looking at $f:\mathbb{P}^1_k\rightarrow\operatorname{Spec}k$ and $A$ a non rational point ? It is easy to check that if $k(A)$ is an extension of degree $n$, $A$ is rationally equivalent to the sum of $n$ rational points. Am I missing something ?

Comment: @Roland Presumably the OP wanted a geometric example. That certainly works though.

Answer (score 1):

Any two points on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are rationally equivalent.

Now consider the proper map from the circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ to the $x$-axis (where we really mean the projective model of this equation, of course).

The point $(1, 0)$ maps to $1$ and the points $(0, 1)$ and $(0, -1)$ both map to $0$. Since the circle is isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$, all of these points in the domain are rationally equivalent.

Without the multiplicity, you'd therefore have $2[0] \sim [1]$ on the target, which isn't right. The point is that the right hand side should be $2[1]$ to account for the ramification.